# Cannot migrate databases using Laravel/Homestead

Tags: php, laravel, homestead

I am using Homestead for a Laravel project.

The Homestead database works fine while using it. I can read, edit, delete...

However when I try to use `php artisan:migrate` in the terminal I get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

So my application has access to the database, but not in the terminal.

Any help?

Comment: try php artisan config:clear

Comment: @Rp9 it helped. You may want to put it as answer

Comment: will do now,please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Running the above command will clear configuration cache file and hence laravel will read the fresh data from the .env file.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure  your database credentials .

Configure those credentials  in .env files

Restart your server  after changes done.

Comment: @prgrm good works ..! kindly clarified you answer .. if you restart server it will generate new configuration .